# How to remove ad limit

Tags: android, admob

I am facing ad limit since 9 months
This is my app - [App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allsocialvideo.downloaderfreeandfastvideodownloader)

I am using native ad interstitial ad only , I have tried everything to fix this issues but nothing happened can anyone check my app and give solutions please.
Sorry for my bad English .